# the argument type object cann't be assigned to parameter like string in flutter while accessing the map inside the list

Tags: flutter, list, dart, object, mapping

```
//my code:
var _index = 0;
  var question = [
    {
      'Questionkey': "which cryptocurrency do you like",
      'Answer': ['bitcoin', 'etherium']
    },
    {
      'Questionkey': "and why do you like that?",
      'Answer': ['stable', 'acutally i don\'t know ']
    },
  ];



question[_index]['Questionkey']//accessing the question but I am getting error while accessing
```

//question is the list that consists of maps and I want to access the question which is pointed questionkey key

Comment: It's the right way to do it. You just have a typo. `' Questionkey'` instead of `'Questionkey'`. Notice the space in front

Comment: still getting same error

Comment: What error are you getting? the literal code you posted here works just fine and correctly

Comment: The argument type 'Object?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String'.dartargument_type_not_assignable

Comment: This code works on dartpad.

Comment: children: [
          Question(question[_index]['Questionkey']),
          Answer(Printanswer),
          Answer(Printanswer),] // Question is class inside which I am passing the value but in flutter it is showing me error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wherever you use

```
question[_index]['Questionkey']
```

write

```
question[_index]['Questionkey'] as String
```

instead. It's able to access the map just fine, it's just that it can't determine the type at compile time. And I assume you are using it at a spot where it requires to be a `String`. Knowing that it is a `String` you can safely cast it like this